# Update multiple columns of the table

Tags: laravel-5

when I update some columns of the table it insert new field in table

```
"id": 1,
"invoice_id": "0001-2019-20",
"client_id": "1",
"currency_id": "4",
"date": "2019-06-06",
"subject": "wordpress",
"total": "3000"
```

when i update only subject and total it will insert new field

```
"id": 2,
"invoice_id": "",
"client_id": "0",
"currency_id": "0",
"date": "0000-00-00",
"subject": "OMS",
"total": "0"
```

here is my controller,

```
$invoices = new Invoice;
$invoices->client_id = $request->get('client_id');
$invoices->currency_id = $request->get('currency_id');;
$invoices->subject = $request->get('subject');
$invoices->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is for creating a new record.
However you are almost there.

So let's say you want to update below data

```
{"id": 1,
"invoice_id": "0001-2019-20",
"client_id": "1",
"currency_id": "4",
"date": "2019-06-06",
"subject": "wordpress",
"total": "3000"}
```

Use Below Code to update that row.

```
$invoices = Invoice::find($request->get('id'));
$invoices->client_id = $request->get('client_id');
$invoices->currency_id = $request->get('currency_id');
$invoices->subject = $request->get('subject');
$invoices->save();
```

There are alternative method as below.

```
$invoices = Invoice::find($request->get('id'));
$invoices->update([
    'client_id' => $request->get('client_id'),
    'currency_id' => $request->get('currency_id'),
    'subject' => $request->get('subject')
]);
```

> Note: For above method array key names and your table column names
>   must be same.